# Possible improvements to this Syracuse (3x+1)/2 graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, number-theory

This algorithm produces the Syracuse disjoint tree graph without any duplicates. No need for `Union,` `For,` and `While.` The function `α` is based on this [OEIS sequence.](https://oeis.org/A047241) The function `β` is a wrapper for `IntegerExponent.`  [Related math.SE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306087)

```
    α[n_] := 3 n - (5 + (-1)^n)/2  
    β[m_] := IntegerExponent[m, 2]  
    a = Table[Join[
                  {Table[x -> (x = (3 x + 1)/2), {β[(x = α[j]) + 1] - 1}]},
                  {x -> (3 x + 1)/2^β[3 x + 1]}
                  ],
             {j, 1, 150}];
    Graph[Flatten[a]]
```

Fifteen sequences:[image: Fifteen sequences], 150 sequences:         [image: One hundred fifty sequences]

**Edit** It seems I was abusing the set-builder notation, so my question at math.SE will not parallel the *Mathematica* statements. So, this question remains: Is there any way to improve the `Table` expression? It was suggested that `NestList[]` might be the ticket.

Comment: `NestList[]` might make for a cleaner implementation here, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're setting  `x` as a side-effect and that (I believe) makes your code difficult to follow.  This one is equivalent using a "more functional" programing style.

As [@Guesswhoitis suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84821/possible-improvements-to-this-syracuse-3x1-2-graph/84924?noredirect=1#comment230157_84821), `NestList[]` is your friend.

```
a[n_] := 3 n - (5 + (-1)^n)/2
b[m_] := IntegerExponent[m, 2]
nextSeq[n_] := (#/2^b@#) &[1 + 3 n]
full[j_] := NestList[nextSeq, a@j, b[a@j + 1]]
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ full /@ Range@15, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't know anything about set-builder notation, but perhaps the following is an approximation:

$$\{(f^k(a(j)), f^{k+1}(a(j))) \ | \ \{ k,j\} \in \mathbb{Z}\ \wedge\ \ 0\le\ k \le\ b(a(j)+1) - 1\ \wedge 0\le\ j \le\ n \}$$

($f$ is the  `nextSeq[ ]` function in the above snippet)

```
GraphicsGrid@
 Partition[
   Graph[DirectedEdge @@@Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] &/@ full/@ Range@#,1]]&/@ Range@50, 
          10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "setting `x` as a side-effect" - after all, that is how one would do Collatz in a procedural language. Thanks for showing OP the `NestList[]` route! (Tho, what I had in mind involved `Partition[]` as well as `NestList[]`.)

Comment: Still computer-less, unfortunately, but let me run through my scratch paper again, and I'll get back to you with a sketch.

Comment: @FredKline I posted a far better version that doesn't need a separated logic for the last element

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. there you've it :)

Comment: Ah, that's more or less what I had in my paper. Thanks for following through, and I'm sorry I can't upvote again.

Comment: I like your answer, but for my paper I have to describe it from a different perspective which is why I posted the temporary answer.  Let me know if you see anything that is awry. I'll delete it in a few days. Thanks for everything. This goes for @Guesswhoitis., too.

Comment: @FredKline Perhaps $\{(f^k(a(j)), f^{k+1}(a(j))) \ | \ \{ k,j\} \in \mathbb{Z}\ \wedge\ \ 0\le\ k \le\ b(a(j)+1) - 1\ \wedge 0\le\ j \le\ n \}$ ?

Comment: where $f$ is `nextSeq[n_] ` in the code above

Comment: I like it. My new version is based the prism I use in my proofs. So, I think I will be using both methods for the graphing part of the paper. Should I delete the temporary answer now?

Comment: @FredKline Oh, I don't understand your geometric visualization, so I can't evaluate how significant is your answer. Sorry, it's up to you :)